# Drag & Drop Filename Visual (Managed) C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, drag-and-drop

I have a RichTextBox that I would like to allow a user to drag and drop a file from disk into. All that should appear in the textbox is the filename(s). This code currently adds `"System.String[]"` to the textbox instead of the filename. When I change the `DataFormats::FileDrop` to `DataFormats::Text` as [this MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/fkw1hc6t%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) would seem to suggest, I get a NULL dereference error.

The RichTextBox name is `rtbFile`. In my constructor, I have:

```
this->rtbFile->AllowDrop = true;
```

I set up the events like this (within InitializeComponents):

```
this->rtbFile->DragEnter += gcnew System::Windows::Forms::DragEventHandler(this, &VanicheMain::rtbFile_DragEnter);
this->rtbFile->DragDrop += gcnew System::Windows::Forms::DragEventHandler(this, &VanicheMain::rtbFile_DragDrop);
```

The functions are defined as follows:

```
void rtbFile_DragEnter(System::Object ^sender, System::Windows::Forms::DragEventArgs ^ e) {
    if (e->Data->GetDataPresent(DataFormats::FileDrop))
        e->Effect = DragDropEffects::Copy;
    else
        e->Effect = DragDropEffects::None;
}

System::Void rtbFile_DragDrop(System::Object ^sender, System::Windows::Forms::DragEventArgs ^e){
    int i = rtbFile->SelectionStart;;
    String ^s = rtbFile->Text->Substring(i);
    rtbFile->Text = rtbFile->Text->Substring(0, i);
    String ^str = String::Concat(rtbFile->Text, e->Data->GetData(DataFormats::FileDrop)->ToString());
    rtbFile->Text = String::Concat(str, s);
}
```

Comment: Right, I am using FileDrop. The issue is that it is printing out "System.String[]" instead of the filename. I'd really like to get the file name.

Comment: Would you happen to have an example handy?

Comment: The LoadFile function takes the file path as the parameter. Also, the ^str variable is apparently not an array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dragging files always produces an array of strings.  Each array element is the path to one of the files that are dragged.  You'll need to write the extra code to cast the return value of GetData() to an array and iterate it, reading the content of each file.  Similar to this:

```
array<String^>^ paths = safe_cast<array<String^>^>(e->Data->GetData(DataFormats::FileDrop));
for each (String^ path in paths) {
    String^ ext = System::IO::Path::GetExtension(path)->ToLower();
    if (ext == ".txt") rtbFile->AppendText(System::IO::File::ReadAllText(path));
}
```